# SVG animate layers z-index

Tags: css, svg

Im trying to animate the groups in my SVG in a way that hovering on  will scale it up.

Im encountering a problem that i cannot set the Z-index in a way that the hovered layer will display on top

Here you can see that the scaled layer is being displayed behind the brown layer

```
https://www.screencast.com/t/agRWZTSUsBzE
```

Here is my code

```js
var map_links = [{"map_area":"har-hanegev","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%94%d7%a8-%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%92%d7%91","hover_color":"#62493d","tooltip":"<p>\u05d4\u05e8 \u05d4\u05e0\u05d2\u05d1<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"beer-sheva","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%91%d7%90%d7%a8-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%a2","hover_color":"#267a73","tooltip":"<p>\u05d1\u05d0\u05e8 \u05e9\u05d1\u05e2<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"arava","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91%d7%94","hover_color":"#be791c","tooltip":"<p>\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1\u05d4<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"negev-north","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a6%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%92%d7%91","hover_color":"#89992d","tooltip":"<p>\u05e6\u05e4\u05d5\u05df \u05d4\u05e0\u05d2\u05d1<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"lachish","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%93-%d7%95%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%94%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%97","hover_color":"#937a58","tooltip":"<p>\u05d7\u05d1\u05dc \u05dc\u05db\u05d9\u05e9 \u05d5\u05d9\u05ea\u05d9\u05e8<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"arad","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%93-%d7%95%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%94%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%97","hover_color":"#56a7a3","tooltip":"<p>\u05e2\u05e8\u05d3 \u05d5\u05d9\u05dd \u05d4\u05de\u05dc\u05d7<\/p>\n"}];
```

```css
.st0{fill:#A68A64;}
.st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
.st2{fill:#A2DAF4;}
.st3{fill:#2E8982;}
.st4{fill:#A7B610;}
.st5{fill:#D8E748;}
.st6{fill:#E69005;}
.st7{fill:#FFCE7D;}
.st8{fill:#715646;}
.st9{fill:#9A7C6B;}
.st10{fill:#68C6C2;}
.st11{fill:#4AA09A;}
svg{
  width:200px;
}
.svg_area:hover{
  animation: popup 500ms ease;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transform-origin: center;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="map_wrap">
     <script>
    
</script>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 61.8 124.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.8 124.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<g data-area="arava" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st6" d="M53.3,46.7C43.2,52.3,36.5,63.5,34,67.7l-0.1,0.1c-0.4,0.6-0.7,1.1-0.8,1.4c-4.9,7.1-4.3,26.3-3.5,37.1l0,0.2
  c0,0.3,0,0.4,0,0.5c0,0.8-0.8,2.7-1.5,4.1l0,0.1l0.5,1.4v1.1c0,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.3c0.2,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,1.7c0,0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.1
  c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,1,0.3,2.6,0.6,3.4c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.8c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.6,1.2l0.1,0.4l0.3-0.3
  c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2l0.1-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.2
  c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.4c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4-0.7c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.5l0.1,0l0.4-0.3l0.4-0.5
  l-0.3-0.2l0.8-2.1l0-0.1c0-0.1-0.1-0.5,0.7-1.2l0.1-0.1l0-1.1l0.4-1.2l0.2-2.6l0,0c0.1-0.1,0.9-1.1,0.8-2.3c0,0,1.1-2.5,1.2-2.9
  c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7c0.3-0.7,0.5-1.2,0.1-2.2l0.1-3.5l0.8-1l0-0.1c0-0.4,0.2-2.2,0.3-2.8c0.1-1.2,0.7-2.4,2.2-3.7
  c0.1-0.1,1.6-1.5,0.6-4.5l-0.8-3l0.6-2.2l0,0c0-0.3,0-1.9,1.2-3.7l0.1-0.1l-0.3-2l-1-1.2l0.2-1.8c0.2-0.3,0.9-1.5,1-2.8l0.7-2.4
  l0,0c0-0.3,0-1.7,0.6-3l2.2-4.2c0.2-0.2,1.4-1.5,1.5-3.5c0-0.6,0.1-2.4,1-2.9l0.1,0l0-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
  c0.4-0.3,0.9-0.7,0.5-1.7l0,0c0-0.1-0.1-3,1.6-4.5l0.1-0.1c0.8-0.4,1.4-0.8,1.7-1.4l0.2-0.6L53.3,46.7z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M35,76.5l2.4,1.1l-0.3,0.6l-1.9-0.9l-0.6,1.4l-0.4-0.2L35,76.5z M35.2,78.9l0.3-0.6l1.3,0.6l-0.3,0.6
   L35.2,78.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M38.5,75.2l-0.9,1.9l-0.4-0.2l0.5-1.1l-1.5-0.7l-0.5,1.1L35.2,76l0.7-1.6l1.9,0.9L38,75L38.5,75.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.6,73c0.3-0.6,0.8-0.5,1.4-0.3l1.3,0.6L39,74l-1.3-0.6c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.8,0.1l-0.3,0.7l-0.4-0.2
   L36.6,73z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M38.1,69.9c0,0,0.5,0.2,1,0.4c0.7,0.3,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.5c0,0.3-0.2,1.3-0.2,1.3L39.3,73l0.1-0.7l-2.2-0.5
   l0.3-0.6l2,0.5c0-0.4,0-0.6-0.6-0.8l-1-0.5L38.1,69.9z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.9,88.7v0.2h-1.3v-0.2h0.8v-1.1h-0.8v-0.2h1.1v1.3H31.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33.3,87.4v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H33.3z M32.2,88.1h0.3v0.9h-0.3V88.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.1,87.4v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H34.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M35.6,87.4v1.9h-0.3v-1.9H35.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.3,87.4v0.8H36v-0.8H36.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37.9,87.4V88c0,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.7,0.2l-0.1-0.2l0.4-0.2l-0.3-1.4H37l0.2,1.3
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.4-0.6v-0.7H37.9z"></path>
 </g>
 <circle class="st7" cx="39.2" cy="88.1" r="0.5"></circle>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.4,94.4h-1.2v-1.6h0.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6V94.4z M32.1,93.5c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.1h0.7V93.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33,92.9v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H33z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.7,92.9v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h0v-0.2h0c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.6v-0.5h-1v-0.2H34.7z M33.5,93.5h0.2v1.4
   h-0.2V93.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M35.4,92.9v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H35.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37,93.4c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6h-1.2v-0.2h0.8l-0.9-1.3H36l0.5,0.8c0.2,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-0.5H37
   V93.4z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.4,100.1c0,0-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.7c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3H31v-0.2h0.8v0.2h-0.3
   c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.4c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1,0.7H31.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.7,98.5c0.4,0,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.5v-0.2h0.6c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4v-0.3
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.3v0.6h-0.2v-0.8H32.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.1,98.5v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H34.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M35.6,98.5l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H35.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.8,100.1l-0.6-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.3l0,0.6h-0.3v-0.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.5l-0.3-0.5H36l0.5,0.8
   c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.3v-0.5h0.2V99c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6H36.8z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M30.6,112.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.4h-0.5V114H30v-1.1h-0.2v-0.2
   H30.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.6,112.7l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H32.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33.2,112.7v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H33.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.6,114.2l-0.6-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.3l0,0.6h-0.3v-0.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.5l-0.3-0.5h0.3l0.5,0.8
   c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.3v-0.5h0.2v0.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6H34.6z"></path>
 </g>
 <circle class="st7" cx="38.4" cy="93.6" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st7" cx="34.5" cy="101.3" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st7" cx="32" cy="115.4" r="0.5"></circle>
</g>
<g data-area="lachish" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st0" d="M25,0l1.5,0.5c1.8,0.6,4.4,1.7,7,3.7c1.1,0.8,1.8,2.1,2,3.8l0,0.2l0.2,0C36.3,8.3,38.8,9,40.9,9
  c0.7,0,1.4-0.1,1.9-0.3c0.8-0.3,2.4-1.5,2.8-2.8c0.2-0.5,0.1-1-0.2-1.4c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.1-0.7c0.2-0.9,1.8-2.1,4.4-3.3l1-0.5H25
  z"></path>
 <g style="display: inline;" class="toggle">
  <path class="st1" d="M35.9,2.3v0.7c0,0.5-0.2,0.7-0.7,0.7h-0.8l-0.1-1.4h0.3l0.1,1.1h0.3c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.4V2.3H35.9z
    M35.3,3.1H35V2.3h0.3V3.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.6,2.3V3h-0.3V2.3H36.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37.3,2.3c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.5h-0.4V3.4h0.4c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4V2.9
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4V2.3H37.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M39.1,2.3l-0.5,1.4h-0.3l0.4-1.1h-0.7V2h0.3v0.3H39.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M41,2.3l-0.5,1.4h-0.3l0.4-1.1h-0.7V2h0.3v0.3H41z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M42.3,3.7h-1.1l0-0.3h0.6V2.5h-0.6V2.3h0.9v1.1h0.2V3.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M43.3,2.3c0.4,0,0.4,0.2,0.4,0.6v0.8h-0.3V2.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4h-0.3v1.1h-0.3V2.3H43.3z"></path>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <path class="st2" d="M60.5,17.6v-0.6l-0.1-1.8v-1.2c-0.2-0.7,0.6-1.5,0.6-2.3c0-0.6,0.1-0.9,0.1-1.4l0.7-4.6c0-1.1-1-1.1-1.7-1
  l-1-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.2c-0.3,0-0.4,0.3-0.5,0.5c-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.2c-0.7,0.8-1.9,1.2-1.9,2.6
  c0,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.7c-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.3c-0.2,0.8-0.9,1.3-0.9,2.3c0,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.4,1.4
  c0,0.3-0.5,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.6l-0.2,1c-0.1,0.2,0,0.8,0,1.1c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V20c0.1,0.7-0.5,1.3-0.5,2
  c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.3,0.5v0.9c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.2l-0.1,0.6c0,0.3,0.4,1,0.4,1.4c0,0.5-0.4,0.7-0.4,1.2c0,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.2
  c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c-0.8,1.3-1.5,2.7-1.4,3.4l0,0.1l0,0.1c-0.1,0.2,0,0.5,0.2,0.8c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0
  c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.3-0.2c-0.1,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4l0.1,1v1c0.3,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.5c0.1,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.8,1.2v0.6
  c0.3,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.3,1.3c0.1,0.3,0.9,0.2,1.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2l1.6,0.3c0.5-0.3,1.8-0.5,1.9-1.4c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2
  l-0.5-1c0.1-0.5,0.3-0.6,0.7-1.1c0.1-0.1,0.4-0.5,0.4-0.9c0-1.3-1.2-1.5-2.3-1.8c-0.4-2.2-0.7-4.5-1-6.6c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2
  c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.9c0.3-0.7,0.9-1.3,1.3-1.7h0.1c0.1,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.5,1.1c0,0.6-0.5,1.4-0.5,2.2c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5
  c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.6-0.4c0.5-0.4,1-0.9,1-1.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4l-0.2-0.6c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0-0.4
  c0-1,0.8-1.6,0.9-2.4v-0.6C61,21.4,61,20.1,61,20c0-0.1-0.1-0.1,0-0.2c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.5
  c0-0.2-0.1-0.4,0-0.6C60.6,18.6,60.6,17.9,60.5,17.6z"></path>
</g>
<g data-area="beer-sheva" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st3" d="M34.4,16.5l-0.2-0.2l-0.2,0.2c-0.8,0.8-3.4,3.5-6,3.3c-10.1-0.6-11.8,1.1-12.6,2c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.5
  c-1.1,0.6-4.5,0.8-4.9,0.8l-2.9,1.2l0.2,0.3c5.7,6,11.6,7.2,15.6,7.2c1.9,0,3.3-0.2,4.2-0.4c11.7-1.9,15.4-6.3,16.1-7.1l0.1-0.2
  L34.4,16.5z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M19.5,24.2c0,0,0,0.5,0,1.1c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-1,1.4c-0.3,0.1-1.2,0.4-1.2,0.4l-0.1-0.5l0.7-0.2l-0.5-2.2H18
   l0.4,2c0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.5-0.9v-1.1H19.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M22.1,26.8H20l0-0.5h1.2v-1.6H20v-0.5h1.8v2.1h0.3V26.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.4,24.2v1.3c0,0.9-0.4,1.3-1.3,1.3h-1.4l-0.2-2.6H23l0.2,2.1h0.7c0.5,0,0.9-0.1,0.9-0.8v-1.4H25.4z
    M24.3,25.8h-0.6v-1.6h0.6V25.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28,24.2c0.7,0,0.8,0.5,0.8,1.1v1.5h-0.6v-1.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.4-0.7h-0.7v-0.5H28z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.2,26.8l-0.9-1.5C30,25.4,30,25.5,30,25.8v1h-0.6v-0.9c0-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.6-0.9l-0.6-0.9H30l0.8,1.3
   c0.3,0,0.3-0.2,0.3-0.5v-0.8h0.6v0.7c0,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8l0.7,1H31.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.4,26.8h-2.1l0-0.5h1.2v-1.6h-1.2v-0.5h1.8v2.1h0.3V26.8z"></path>
 </g>
</g>
<g data-area="negev-north" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st4" d="M33.5,4.2C29.2,0.8,24.8,0,24.7,0l-4.9,0l-0.1,0.1c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.8c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,1
  c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.8c-0.3,0.5-0.6,1.1-0.7,1.7c-0.2,0.5-0.6,1-1,1.5c-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.9-0.9,1.4c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.4,0.9
  c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.8c-1,1-1.6,2-2.1,2.9L0,27.4l9.9-4.3c0.5,0,3.8-0.2,4.9-0.8h0c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5-0.5c0.9-1,2.5-2.6,12.6-2
  c2.8,0.2,5.8-3.1,6.1-3.5l0-0.1C34.4,15.9,37.7,7.5,33.5,4.2z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.4,12.5v0.2h-1.3v-0.2h0.8v-1.1h-0.8v-0.2h1.1v1.3H25.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M26.8,11.2v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H26.8z M25.6,11.9h0.3v0.9h-0.3V11.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28.3,11.2l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H28.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29.7,11.2c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9H30v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H29.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.8,11.2v0.6c0,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.7,0.2l-0.1-0.2l0.4-0.2l-0.3-1.4h0.3l0.2,1.3
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.4-0.6v-0.7H31.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.5,11.1V12h-0.3v-0.8H32.5z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.2,16.1v1.6h-0.3v-1.3H24v-0.2H25.2z M24,16.8h0.3v0.9H24V16.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.9,16.1v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H25.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27.5,16.1v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h0v-0.2h0c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.6v-0.5h-1v-0.2H27.5z M26.3,16.6h0.2V18
   h-0.2V16.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29,16.1l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H29z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M16.6,15.1v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h-0.4l-0.2-1.6h0.3l0.1,1.4h0.2c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.7v-0.4H16v-0.2
   H16.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M18.2,15.1v1.6h-0.3v-1.3H17v-0.2H18.2z M17,15.8h0.3v0.9H17V15.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M19,15.1c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H19z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M9.8,18.9l-0.6,1.6H9l0.5-1.3H8.7v-0.5h0.2v0.3H9.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M10.4,18.9v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H10.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M11.2,18.9c0.4,0,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.4v-0.2h0.4c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4v-0.3
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.5v-0.2H11.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M13.4,18.9h0.3v0.8c0,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.8,0.8h-0.7l-0.1-1.6h0.3l0.1,1.4h0.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.5V18.9z
    M13,18.9v1h-0.2v-1H13z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M15.1,20.4l-0.6-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.3l0,0.6h-0.3v-0.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.5l-0.3-0.5h0.3l0.5,0.8
   c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.3v-0.5h0.2v0.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6H15.1z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M20.2,9.4h-1.7l0-0.4h0.9V7.7h-0.9V7.3h1.4V9h0.2V9.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M21.1,8.8c-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.5h-0.1V8.9h0.2c0.4,0,0.5-0.3,0.5-0.7C21,8,21,7.7,21,7.7h-0.4V7.3h0.8
   l0.3,2.1h-0.4L21.1,8.8L21.1,8.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M22.2,9c0.2,0,0.2,0,0.2-0.3v-1h-0.3V7.3h0.8v1.5c0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.5h-0.5V9H22.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25,7.3v2.1h-0.5V7.7h-1.2V7.3H25z M23.3,8.3h0.5v1.1h-0.5V8.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27,7.3v2.6h-0.5V7.3H27z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28.1,7.3v2.1h-0.5V7.3H28.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29.5,7.3c0.6,0,0.8,0.3,0.8,0.8v0.4c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.8,0.8h-0.9V9h0.8c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.5V8.2
   c0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.4-0.5h-0.3v0.8h-0.4V7.3H29.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.4,7.9c0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.6,0.7l0.5,0.8h-1.7V9h1l-1.1-1.7h0.5l0.6,1c0.3,0,0.3-0.2,0.3-0.4V7.3h0.5V7.9z"></path>
 </g>
 <circle class="st5" cx="16.4" cy="19.6" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st5" cx="20.6" cy="15.9" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st5" cx="29.9" cy="16.9" r="0.5"></circle>
 <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6972 -0.7169 0.7169 0.6972 1.3889 27.7289)" class="st5" cx="33.5" cy="12.2" rx="0.5" ry="0.5"></ellipse>
</g>


<g data-area="arad" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st10" d="M50.7,0l-0.1,0c-0.2,0.1-4.9,2.2-5.3,3.8c-0.1,0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7c0.3,0.4,0.4,0.9,0.2,1.4
  c-0.4,1.3-2,2.5-2.8,2.8C42.3,8.9,41.7,9,40.9,9c-2,0-4.3-0.6-5-0.8l-0.3-0.1l0,0.4c0.3,3.3-1,7-1.3,7.6l-0.1,0.2l19.1,16.2
  l-0.1-0.7c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4l0,0l0,0c0-0.7,0.6-2,1.2-3l0.1-0.2l-0.2-0.1v-0.2l-0.4,0c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4
  c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.7c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5l0.2-0.7c0-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.3v-1.1l-0.2-0.1
  c-0.1,0-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.8c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.3-1.2v-1.4c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3
  c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0-0.2,0-0.6,0-0.7l0.2-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6-0.9
  c0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.6c0-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.5-1.3c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.4-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7
  c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2
  c0-0.7,0.3-1.1,0.6-1.4L56.4,7l0-0.1c0.6-3.4,1.3-5.7,1.6-6.6L58.1,0H50.7z"></path>
 <g>
  <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6972 -0.7169 0.7169 0.6972 5.8185 36.4232)" class="st11" cx="46" cy="11.3" rx="0.5" ry="0.5"></ellipse>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path class="st1" d="M41.8,12v-1.3h-0.7v-0.2h1.2v0.2h-0.2V12H41.8z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M43,10.4c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7V12h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H43z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M45,10.4v0.6c0,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.7,0.2l-0.1-0.2l0.4-0.2l-0.3-1.4h0.3l0.2,1.3
     c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.4-0.6v-0.7H45z"></path>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6972 -0.7169 0.7169 0.6972 1.3986 42.8694)" class="st11" cx="51.4" cy="19.8" rx="0.5" ry="0.5"></ellipse>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path class="st1" d="M42.1,19.1c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4h-0.4v1.3h-0.3v-1.6H42.1z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M44,19.1l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H44z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M44.8,20.4h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2h0.7
     c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8v0.8h-0.7V20.4z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M47,19.1v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H47z M45.8,19.8h0.3v0.9h-0.3V19.8z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M49.4,20.7h-1.2v-1.6h0.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6V20.7z M49.2,19.7c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.1h0.7V19.7z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M50.1,19.1v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H50.1z"></path>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g data-area="har-hanegev" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st8" d="M55.5,40.2l0.2-0.3l-0.6-0.1l0,0h0c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0c-0.3,0-0.7,0-0.8-0.1
  c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.2-0.7l0-0.5c0.1-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.5-1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6
  c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.3-1l0-1l-0.1-0.9c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.1C52.7,33,53,33,53.2,33l0.2,0l0.2-0.3l-10.2-8.6
  l-0.2,0.2c-0.9,1.2-4.7,5.2-16.1,7.1c-0.9,0.1-2.4,0.4-4.2,0.4c-5.9,0-11.2-2.5-15.8-7.3l-0.1-0.1L0,27.4l2.1,5.3l0.2,0.5l0,0
  l5.8,18.6L9,54.1l0.5,1.2c2.6,5.8,2.6,5.8,3.2,8.5c0.2,0.7,0.4,1.6,0.7,2.8c0.1,0.5,0.1,0.9,0,1.5c0,0.4-0.1,0.9-0.1,1.6l0,0.1
  l1.7,2.2l-0.7,2.7l0.1,1.4l3.2,2.3c0,0.5,0.3,1.3,0.5,1.7l0.2,0.7c1.7,4.8,5.1,14.8,5.6,16.1l0.1,0.2h0c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7
  l0,0.9l4.1,12.6l0.3-0.6c0.4-0.8,1.3-2.8,1.3-3.6c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.6l0-0.1c-0.8-10.8-1.4-30,3.5-37.1c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.8,0.9-1.5
  c2.6-4.3,9.4-15.6,19.7-21.1l0.1-0.1l0-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5c0,0-0.2-0.7,0.1-1.8
  C53.8,42.7,55.3,40.5,55.5,40.2z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.3,41.7h-1.2v-1.6h0.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6V41.7z M36.1,40.8c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.1h0.7V40.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37.4,40.2c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4H37v1.3h-0.3v-1.6H37.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M38.6,40.2v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H38.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M39.4,40.2c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4H39v-0.2H39.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M40.7,40.2V41h-0.3v-0.8H40.7z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M21,50.1h-2.1l0-0.5h1.2v-1.6h-1.2v-0.5h1.8v2.1H21V50.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M22.2,49.4c-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.7-0.8,0.7h-0.1v-0.5h0.3c0.5,0,0.6-0.4,0.6-0.8c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-0.7h-0.5v-0.5h1
   l0.3,2.6h-0.5L22.2,49.4L22.2,49.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M23.5,49.6c0.2,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-1.3h-0.4v-0.5h1v1.9c0,0.5-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.7h-0.6v-0.5H23.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27,47.5v2.6h-0.6v-2.1h-1.5v-0.5H27z M24.9,48.7h0.6v1.4h-0.6V48.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29.7,47.5c0.7,0,0.8,0.5,0.8,1.1v1.5h-0.6v-1.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.4-0.7h-0.7v-0.5H29.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33.2,47.5v2.6h-0.6v-2.1h-1.5v-0.5H33.2z M31.1,48.7h0.6v1.4h-0.6V48.7z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M21.2,57.5c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H21.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M23.4,57.5v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h0v-0.2h0c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.6v-0.5h-1v-0.2H23.4z M22.2,58.1h0.2v1.4
   h-0.2V58.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M24.1,57.5v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H24.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.7,58.8v0.2h-1.3v-0.2h0.8v-1.1h-0.8v-0.2h1.1v1.3H25.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28,57.5v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H28z M26.8,58.2H27v0.9h-0.3V58.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29,59.1v-1.3h-0.7v-0.2h1.2v0.2h-0.2v1.3H29z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.1,57.5h0.3v0.8c0,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.8,0.8h-0.7l-0.1-1.6H30l0.1,1.4h0.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.5V57.5z
    M30.7,57.5v1h-0.2v-1H30.7z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M17.7,66.8v1.9h-0.3v-1.9H17.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M18.5,66.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H18.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M19.4,68.2h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2h0.7c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8
   v0.8h-0.7V68.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M20.9,66.8c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H20.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M23.7,66.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H23.7z M22.6,67.5h0.3v0.9h-0.3V67.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M24.7,66.8c0.4,0,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.5v-0.2h0.6c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4v-0.3
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.3v0.6h-0.2v-0.8H24.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27,67.3c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6h-1.2v-0.2h0.8l-0.9-1.3H26l0.5,0.8c0.2,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-0.5H27
   V67.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27.9,68.2h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2H28c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8
   v0.8h-0.7V68.2z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M41.5,34.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H41.5z M40.4,35.5h0.3v0.9h-0.3V35.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M42,36.2c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-0.9H42v-0.2h0.5v1.1c0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.4h-0.2v-0.2H42z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M43.2,34.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H43.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M44.2,36.2h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2h0.7c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8
   v0.8h-0.7V36.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M45.5,34.8v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H45.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M46.6,36.4v-1.3h-0.7v-0.2H47v0.2h-0.2v1.3H46.6z"></path>
 </g>
 
 
 
 
</g></svg>
    </div>
```

```
https://codepen.io/regevlio/pen/dRVjOE
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Can you put your [mcve] in the question please rather than adding it as links. If something happens to the links your question won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use z-index in SVG.

The way SVG works is that items that appear down the DOM tree have "higher z-index", so you will have to remove the items and append them at the end of your dom:

```
$('.svg_area').hover(function() {
    $('svg').append(this)
});
```

Here is a working example based on your code:

```js
var map_links = [{"map_area":"har-hanegev","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%94%d7%a8-%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%92%d7%91","hover_color":"#62493d","tooltip":"<p>\u05d4\u05e8 \u05d4\u05e0\u05d2\u05d1<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"beer-sheva","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%91%d7%90%d7%a8-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%a2","hover_color":"#267a73","tooltip":"<p>\u05d1\u05d0\u05e8 \u05e9\u05d1\u05e2<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"arava","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91%d7%94","hover_color":"#be791c","tooltip":"<p>\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1\u05d4<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"negev-north","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a6%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%92%d7%91","hover_color":"#89992d","tooltip":"<p>\u05e6\u05e4\u05d5\u05df \u05d4\u05e0\u05d2\u05d1<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"lachish","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%93-%d7%95%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%94%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%97","hover_color":"#937a58","tooltip":"<p>\u05d7\u05d1\u05dc \u05dc\u05db\u05d9\u05e9 \u05d5\u05d9\u05ea\u05d9\u05e8<\/p>\n"},{"map_area":"arad","link":"http:\/whatever\/?region_cat=%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%93-%d7%95%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%94%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%97","hover_color":"#56a7a3","tooltip":"<p>\u05e2\u05e8\u05d3 \u05d5\u05d9\u05dd \u05d4\u05de\u05dc\u05d7<\/p>\n"}];

$('.svg_area').hover(function() {
  $('svg').append(this)
});
```

```css
.st0{fill:#A68A64;}
.st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
.st2{fill:#A2DAF4;}
.st3{fill:#2E8982;}
.st4{fill:#A7B610;}
.st5{fill:#D8E748;}
.st6{fill:#E69005;}
.st7{fill:#FFCE7D;}
.st8{fill:#715646;}
.st9{fill:#9A7C6B;}
.st10{fill:#68C6C2;}
.st11{fill:#4AA09A;}
svg{
  width:200px;
}
.svg_area:hover{
  animation: popup 500ms ease;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transform-origin: center;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map_wrap">
     <script>
    
</script>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 61.8 124.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.8 124.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<g data-area="arava" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st6" d="M53.3,46.7C43.2,52.3,36.5,63.5,34,67.7l-0.1,0.1c-0.4,0.6-0.7,1.1-0.8,1.4c-4.9,7.1-4.3,26.3-3.5,37.1l0,0.2
  c0,0.3,0,0.4,0,0.5c0,0.8-0.8,2.7-1.5,4.1l0,0.1l0.5,1.4v1.1c0,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.3c0.2,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,1.7c0,0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.1
  c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,1,0.3,2.6,0.6,3.4c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.8c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.6,1.2l0.1,0.4l0.3-0.3
  c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2l0.1-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.2
  c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.4c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4-0.7c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.5l0.1,0l0.4-0.3l0.4-0.5
  l-0.3-0.2l0.8-2.1l0-0.1c0-0.1-0.1-0.5,0.7-1.2l0.1-0.1l0-1.1l0.4-1.2l0.2-2.6l0,0c0.1-0.1,0.9-1.1,0.8-2.3c0,0,1.1-2.5,1.2-2.9
  c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7c0.3-0.7,0.5-1.2,0.1-2.2l0.1-3.5l0.8-1l0-0.1c0-0.4,0.2-2.2,0.3-2.8c0.1-1.2,0.7-2.4,2.2-3.7
  c0.1-0.1,1.6-1.5,0.6-4.5l-0.8-3l0.6-2.2l0,0c0-0.3,0-1.9,1.2-3.7l0.1-0.1l-0.3-2l-1-1.2l0.2-1.8c0.2-0.3,0.9-1.5,1-2.8l0.7-2.4
  l0,0c0-0.3,0-1.7,0.6-3l2.2-4.2c0.2-0.2,1.4-1.5,1.5-3.5c0-0.6,0.1-2.4,1-2.9l0.1,0l0-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
  c0.4-0.3,0.9-0.7,0.5-1.7l0,0c0-0.1-0.1-3,1.6-4.5l0.1-0.1c0.8-0.4,1.4-0.8,1.7-1.4l0.2-0.6L53.3,46.7z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M35,76.5l2.4,1.1l-0.3,0.6l-1.9-0.9l-0.6,1.4l-0.4-0.2L35,76.5z M35.2,78.9l0.3-0.6l1.3,0.6l-0.3,0.6
   L35.2,78.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M38.5,75.2l-0.9,1.9l-0.4-0.2l0.5-1.1l-1.5-0.7l-0.5,1.1L35.2,76l0.7-1.6l1.9,0.9L38,75L38.5,75.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.6,73c0.3-0.6,0.8-0.5,1.4-0.3l1.3,0.6L39,74l-1.3-0.6c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.8,0.1l-0.3,0.7l-0.4-0.2
   L36.6,73z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M38.1,69.9c0,0,0.5,0.2,1,0.4c0.7,0.3,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.5c0,0.3-0.2,1.3-0.2,1.3L39.3,73l0.1-0.7l-2.2-0.5
   l0.3-0.6l2,0.5c0-0.4,0-0.6-0.6-0.8l-1-0.5L38.1,69.9z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.9,88.7v0.2h-1.3v-0.2h0.8v-1.1h-0.8v-0.2h1.1v1.3H31.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33.3,87.4v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H33.3z M32.2,88.1h0.3v0.9h-0.3V88.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.1,87.4v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H34.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M35.6,87.4v1.9h-0.3v-1.9H35.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.3,87.4v0.8H36v-0.8H36.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37.9,87.4V88c0,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.7,0.2l-0.1-0.2l0.4-0.2l-0.3-1.4H37l0.2,1.3
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.4-0.6v-0.7H37.9z"></path>
 </g>
 <circle class="st7" cx="39.2" cy="88.1" r="0.5"></circle>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.4,94.4h-1.2v-1.6h0.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6V94.4z M32.1,93.5c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.1h0.7V93.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33,92.9v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H33z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.7,92.9v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h0v-0.2h0c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.6v-0.5h-1v-0.2H34.7z M33.5,93.5h0.2v1.4
   h-0.2V93.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M35.4,92.9v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H35.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37,93.4c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6h-1.2v-0.2h0.8l-0.9-1.3H36l0.5,0.8c0.2,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-0.5H37
   V93.4z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.4,100.1c0,0-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.7c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3H31v-0.2h0.8v0.2h-0.3
   c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.4c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1,0.7H31.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.7,98.5c0.4,0,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.5v-0.2h0.6c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4v-0.3
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.3v0.6h-0.2v-0.8H32.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.1,98.5v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H34.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M35.6,98.5l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H35.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.8,100.1l-0.6-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.3l0,0.6h-0.3v-0.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.5l-0.3-0.5H36l0.5,0.8
   c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.3v-0.5h0.2V99c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6H36.8z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M30.6,112.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.4h-0.5V114H30v-1.1h-0.2v-0.2
   H30.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.6,112.7l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H32.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33.2,112.7v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H33.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.6,114.2l-0.6-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.3l0,0.6h-0.3v-0.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.5l-0.3-0.5h0.3l0.5,0.8
   c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.3v-0.5h0.2v0.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6H34.6z"></path>
 </g>
 <circle class="st7" cx="38.4" cy="93.6" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st7" cx="34.5" cy="101.3" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st7" cx="32" cy="115.4" r="0.5"></circle>
</g>
<g data-area="lachish" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st0" d="M25,0l1.5,0.5c1.8,0.6,4.4,1.7,7,3.7c1.1,0.8,1.8,2.1,2,3.8l0,0.2l0.2,0C36.3,8.3,38.8,9,40.9,9
  c0.7,0,1.4-0.1,1.9-0.3c0.8-0.3,2.4-1.5,2.8-2.8c0.2-0.5,0.1-1-0.2-1.4c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.1-0.7c0.2-0.9,1.8-2.1,4.4-3.3l1-0.5H25
  z"></path>
 <g style="display: inline;" class="toggle">
  <path class="st1" d="M35.9,2.3v0.7c0,0.5-0.2,0.7-0.7,0.7h-0.8l-0.1-1.4h0.3l0.1,1.1h0.3c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.4V2.3H35.9z
    M35.3,3.1H35V2.3h0.3V3.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.6,2.3V3h-0.3V2.3H36.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37.3,2.3c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.5h-0.4V3.4h0.4c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4V2.9
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4V2.3H37.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M39.1,2.3l-0.5,1.4h-0.3l0.4-1.1h-0.7V2h0.3v0.3H39.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M41,2.3l-0.5,1.4h-0.3l0.4-1.1h-0.7V2h0.3v0.3H41z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M42.3,3.7h-1.1l0-0.3h0.6V2.5h-0.6V2.3h0.9v1.1h0.2V3.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M43.3,2.3c0.4,0,0.4,0.2,0.4,0.6v0.8h-0.3V2.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4h-0.3v1.1h-0.3V2.3H43.3z"></path>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <path class="st2" d="M60.5,17.6v-0.6l-0.1-1.8v-1.2c-0.2-0.7,0.6-1.5,0.6-2.3c0-0.6,0.1-0.9,0.1-1.4l0.7-4.6c0-1.1-1-1.1-1.7-1
  l-1-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.2c-0.3,0-0.4,0.3-0.5,0.5c-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.2c-0.7,0.8-1.9,1.2-1.9,2.6
  c0,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.7c-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.3c-0.2,0.8-0.9,1.3-0.9,2.3c0,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.4,1.4
  c0,0.3-0.5,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.6l-0.2,1c-0.1,0.2,0,0.8,0,1.1c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5V20c0.1,0.7-0.5,1.3-0.5,2
  c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.3,0.5v0.9c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.4,1.2l-0.1,0.6c0,0.3,0.4,1,0.4,1.4c0,0.5-0.4,0.7-0.4,1.2c0,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.2
  c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c-0.8,1.3-1.5,2.7-1.4,3.4l0,0.1l0,0.1c-0.1,0.2,0,0.5,0.2,0.8c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0
  c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.3-0.2c-0.1,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4l0.1,1v1c0.3,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.5c0.1,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.8,1.2v0.6
  c0.3,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.3,1.3c0.1,0.3,0.9,0.2,1.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2l1.6,0.3c0.5-0.3,1.8-0.5,1.9-1.4c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2
  l-0.5-1c0.1-0.5,0.3-0.6,0.7-1.1c0.1-0.1,0.4-0.5,0.4-0.9c0-1.3-1.2-1.5-2.3-1.8c-0.4-2.2-0.7-4.5-1-6.6c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2
  c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.9c0.3-0.7,0.9-1.3,1.3-1.7h0.1c0.1,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.5,1.1c0,0.6-0.5,1.4-0.5,2.2c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5
  c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.6-0.4c0.5-0.4,1-0.9,1-1.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4l-0.2-0.6c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0-0.4
  c0-1,0.8-1.6,0.9-2.4v-0.6C61,21.4,61,20.1,61,20c0-0.1-0.1-0.1,0-0.2c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.5
  c0-0.2-0.1-0.4,0-0.6C60.6,18.6,60.6,17.9,60.5,17.6z"></path>
</g>
<g data-area="beer-sheva" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st3" d="M34.4,16.5l-0.2-0.2l-0.2,0.2c-0.8,0.8-3.4,3.5-6,3.3c-10.1-0.6-11.8,1.1-12.6,2c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.5
  c-1.1,0.6-4.5,0.8-4.9,0.8l-2.9,1.2l0.2,0.3c5.7,6,11.6,7.2,15.6,7.2c1.9,0,3.3-0.2,4.2-0.4c11.7-1.9,15.4-6.3,16.1-7.1l0.1-0.2
  L34.4,16.5z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M19.5,24.2c0,0,0,0.5,0,1.1c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-1,1.4c-0.3,0.1-1.2,0.4-1.2,0.4l-0.1-0.5l0.7-0.2l-0.5-2.2H18
   l0.4,2c0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.5-0.9v-1.1H19.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M22.1,26.8H20l0-0.5h1.2v-1.6H20v-0.5h1.8v2.1h0.3V26.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.4,24.2v1.3c0,0.9-0.4,1.3-1.3,1.3h-1.4l-0.2-2.6H23l0.2,2.1h0.7c0.5,0,0.9-0.1,0.9-0.8v-1.4H25.4z
    M24.3,25.8h-0.6v-1.6h0.6V25.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28,24.2c0.7,0,0.8,0.5,0.8,1.1v1.5h-0.6v-1.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.4-0.7h-0.7v-0.5H28z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.2,26.8l-0.9-1.5C30,25.4,30,25.5,30,25.8v1h-0.6v-0.9c0-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.6-0.9l-0.6-0.9H30l0.8,1.3
   c0.3,0,0.3-0.2,0.3-0.5v-0.8h0.6v0.7c0,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8l0.7,1H31.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M34.4,26.8h-2.1l0-0.5h1.2v-1.6h-1.2v-0.5h1.8v2.1h0.3V26.8z"></path>
 </g>
</g>
<g data-area="negev-north" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st4" d="M33.5,4.2C29.2,0.8,24.8,0,24.7,0l-4.9,0l-0.1,0.1c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.8c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,1
  c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.8c-0.3,0.5-0.6,1.1-0.7,1.7c-0.2,0.5-0.6,1-1,1.5c-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.9-0.9,1.4c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.4,0.9
  c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.8c-1,1-1.6,2-2.1,2.9L0,27.4l9.9-4.3c0.5,0,3.8-0.2,4.9-0.8h0c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5-0.5c0.9-1,2.5-2.6,12.6-2
  c2.8,0.2,5.8-3.1,6.1-3.5l0-0.1C34.4,15.9,37.7,7.5,33.5,4.2z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.4,12.5v0.2h-1.3v-0.2h0.8v-1.1h-0.8v-0.2h1.1v1.3H25.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M26.8,11.2v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H26.8z M25.6,11.9h0.3v0.9h-0.3V11.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28.3,11.2l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H28.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29.7,11.2c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9H30v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H29.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.8,11.2v0.6c0,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.7,0.2l-0.1-0.2l0.4-0.2l-0.3-1.4h0.3l0.2,1.3
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.4-0.6v-0.7H31.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.5,11.1V12h-0.3v-0.8H32.5z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.2,16.1v1.6h-0.3v-1.3H24v-0.2H25.2z M24,16.8h0.3v0.9H24V16.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.9,16.1v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H25.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27.5,16.1v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h0v-0.2h0c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.6v-0.5h-1v-0.2H27.5z M26.3,16.6h0.2V18
   h-0.2V16.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29,16.1l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H29z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M16.6,15.1v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h-0.4l-0.2-1.6h0.3l0.1,1.4h0.2c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.7v-0.4H16v-0.2
   H16.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M18.2,15.1v1.6h-0.3v-1.3H17v-0.2H18.2z M17,15.8h0.3v0.9H17V15.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M19,15.1c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H19z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M9.8,18.9l-0.6,1.6H9l0.5-1.3H8.7v-0.5h0.2v0.3H9.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M10.4,18.9v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H10.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M11.2,18.9c0.4,0,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.4v-0.2h0.4c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4v-0.3
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.5v-0.2H11.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M13.4,18.9h0.3v0.8c0,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.8,0.8h-0.7l-0.1-1.6h0.3l0.1,1.4h0.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.5V18.9z
    M13,18.9v1h-0.2v-1H13z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M15.1,20.4l-0.6-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.3l0,0.6h-0.3v-0.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.5l-0.3-0.5h0.3l0.5,0.8
   c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.3v-0.5h0.2v0.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6H15.1z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M20.2,9.4h-1.7l0-0.4h0.9V7.7h-0.9V7.3h1.4V9h0.2V9.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M21.1,8.8c-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.5h-0.1V8.9h0.2c0.4,0,0.5-0.3,0.5-0.7C21,8,21,7.7,21,7.7h-0.4V7.3h0.8
   l0.3,2.1h-0.4L21.1,8.8L21.1,8.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M22.2,9c0.2,0,0.2,0,0.2-0.3v-1h-0.3V7.3h0.8v1.5c0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.5h-0.5V9H22.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25,7.3v2.1h-0.5V7.7h-1.2V7.3H25z M23.3,8.3h0.5v1.1h-0.5V8.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27,7.3v2.6h-0.5V7.3H27z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28.1,7.3v2.1h-0.5V7.3H28.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29.5,7.3c0.6,0,0.8,0.3,0.8,0.8v0.4c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.8,0.8h-0.9V9h0.8c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.5V8.2
   c0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.4-0.5h-0.3v0.8h-0.4V7.3H29.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M32.4,7.9c0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.6,0.7l0.5,0.8h-1.7V9h1l-1.1-1.7h0.5l0.6,1c0.3,0,0.3-0.2,0.3-0.4V7.3h0.5V7.9z"></path>
 </g>
 <circle class="st5" cx="16.4" cy="19.6" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st5" cx="20.6" cy="15.9" r="0.5"></circle>
 <circle class="st5" cx="29.9" cy="16.9" r="0.5"></circle>
 <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6972 -0.7169 0.7169 0.6972 1.3889 27.7289)" class="st5" cx="33.5" cy="12.2" rx="0.5" ry="0.5"></ellipse>
</g>


<g data-area="arad" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st10" d="M50.7,0l-0.1,0c-0.2,0.1-4.9,2.2-5.3,3.8c-0.1,0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.7c0.3,0.4,0.4,0.9,0.2,1.4
  c-0.4,1.3-2,2.5-2.8,2.8C42.3,8.9,41.7,9,40.9,9c-2,0-4.3-0.6-5-0.8l-0.3-0.1l0,0.4c0.3,3.3-1,7-1.3,7.6l-0.1,0.2l19.1,16.2
  l-0.1-0.7c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4l0,0l0,0c0-0.7,0.6-2,1.2-3l0.1-0.2l-0.2-0.1v-0.2l-0.4,0c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4
  c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.7c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5l0.2-0.7c0-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.3v-1.1l-0.2-0.1
  c-0.1,0-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.8c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.3-1.2v-1.4c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3
  c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0-0.2,0-0.6,0-0.7l0.2-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6-0.9
  c0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.6c0-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.5-1.3c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.4-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7
  c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2
  c0-0.7,0.3-1.1,0.6-1.4L56.4,7l0-0.1c0.6-3.4,1.3-5.7,1.6-6.6L58.1,0H50.7z"></path>
 <g>
  <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6972 -0.7169 0.7169 0.6972 5.8185 36.4232)" class="st11" cx="46" cy="11.3" rx="0.5" ry="0.5"></ellipse>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path class="st1" d="M41.8,12v-1.3h-0.7v-0.2h1.2v0.2h-0.2V12H41.8z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M43,10.4c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7V12h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H43z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M45,10.4v0.6c0,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.7,0.2l-0.1-0.2l0.4-0.2l-0.3-1.4h0.3l0.2,1.3
     c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.4-0.6v-0.7H45z"></path>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6972 -0.7169 0.7169 0.6972 1.3986 42.8694)" class="st11" cx="51.4" cy="19.8" rx="0.5" ry="0.5"></ellipse>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path class="st1" d="M42.1,19.1c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4h-0.4v1.3h-0.3v-1.6H42.1z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M44,19.1l-0.6,1.6h-0.3l0.5-1.3h-0.8v-0.5h0.2v0.3H44z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M44.8,20.4h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2h0.7
     c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8v0.8h-0.7V20.4z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M47,19.1v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H47z M45.8,19.8h0.3v0.9h-0.3V19.8z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M49.4,20.7h-1.2v-1.6h0.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6V20.7z M49.2,19.7c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.1h0.7V19.7z"></path>
    <path class="st1" d="M50.1,19.1v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H50.1z"></path>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g data-area="har-hanegev" class="svg_area">
 <path class="st8" d="M55.5,40.2l0.2-0.3l-0.6-0.1l0,0h0c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0c-0.3,0-0.7,0-0.8-0.1
  c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.2-0.7l0-0.5c0.1-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.5-1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6
  c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.3-1l0-1l-0.1-0.9c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.1C52.7,33,53,33,53.2,33l0.2,0l0.2-0.3l-10.2-8.6
  l-0.2,0.2c-0.9,1.2-4.7,5.2-16.1,7.1c-0.9,0.1-2.4,0.4-4.2,0.4c-5.9,0-11.2-2.5-15.8-7.3l-0.1-0.1L0,27.4l2.1,5.3l0.2,0.5l0,0
  l5.8,18.6L9,54.1l0.5,1.2c2.6,5.8,2.6,5.8,3.2,8.5c0.2,0.7,0.4,1.6,0.7,2.8c0.1,0.5,0.1,0.9,0,1.5c0,0.4-0.1,0.9-0.1,1.6l0,0.1
  l1.7,2.2l-0.7,2.7l0.1,1.4l3.2,2.3c0,0.5,0.3,1.3,0.5,1.7l0.2,0.7c1.7,4.8,5.1,14.8,5.6,16.1l0.1,0.2h0c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7
  l0,0.9l4.1,12.6l0.3-0.6c0.4-0.8,1.3-2.8,1.3-3.6c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.6l0-0.1c-0.8-10.8-1.4-30,3.5-37.1c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.8,0.9-1.5
  c2.6-4.3,9.4-15.6,19.7-21.1l0.1-0.1l0-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5c0,0-0.2-0.7,0.1-1.8
  C53.8,42.7,55.3,40.5,55.5,40.2z"></path>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M36.3,41.7h-1.2v-1.6h0.7c0.4,0,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6V41.7z M36.1,40.8c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.4v1.1h0.7V40.8z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M37.4,40.2c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4H37v1.3h-0.3v-1.6H37.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M38.6,40.2v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H38.6z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M39.4,40.2c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.3-0.4H39v-0.2H39.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M40.7,40.2V41h-0.3v-0.8H40.7z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M21,50.1h-2.1l0-0.5h1.2v-1.6h-1.2v-0.5h1.8v2.1H21V50.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M22.2,49.4c-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.7-0.8,0.7h-0.1v-0.5h0.3c0.5,0,0.6-0.4,0.6-0.8c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-0.7h-0.5v-0.5h1
   l0.3,2.6h-0.5L22.2,49.4L22.2,49.4z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M23.5,49.6c0.2,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-1.3h-0.4v-0.5h1v1.9c0,0.5-0.2,0.7-0.6,0.7h-0.6v-0.5H23.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27,47.5v2.6h-0.6v-2.1h-1.5v-0.5H27z M24.9,48.7h0.6v1.4h-0.6V48.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29.7,47.5c0.7,0,0.8,0.5,0.8,1.1v1.5h-0.6v-1.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.4-0.7h-0.7v-0.5H29.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M33.2,47.5v2.6h-0.6v-2.1h-1.5v-0.5H33.2z M31.1,48.7h0.6v1.4h-0.6V48.7z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M21.2,57.5c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H21.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M23.4,57.5v0.8c0,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.7,0.8h0v-0.2h0c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.6v-0.5h-1v-0.2H23.4z M22.2,58.1h0.2v1.4
   h-0.2V58.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M24.1,57.5v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H24.1z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M25.7,58.8v0.2h-1.3v-0.2h0.8v-1.1h-0.8v-0.2h1.1v1.3H25.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M28,57.5v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H28z M26.8,58.2H27v0.9h-0.3V58.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M29,59.1v-1.3h-0.7v-0.2h1.2v0.2h-0.2v1.3H29z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M31.1,57.5h0.3v0.8c0,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.8,0.8h-0.7l-0.1-1.6H30l0.1,1.4h0.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.5V57.5z
    M30.7,57.5v1h-0.2v-1H30.7z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M17.7,66.8v1.9h-0.3v-1.9H17.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M18.5,66.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H18.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M19.4,68.2h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2h0.7c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8
   v0.8h-0.7V68.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M20.9,66.8c0.4,0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.7v0.9h-0.3v-0.9c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.3-0.5h-0.5v-0.2H20.9z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M23.7,66.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H23.7z M22.6,67.5h0.3v0.9h-0.3V67.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M24.7,66.8c0.4,0,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.6v0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.5v-0.2h0.6c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.4v-0.3
   c0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.3v0.6h-0.2v-0.8H24.7z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27,67.3c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.5l0.4,0.6h-1.2v-0.2h0.8l-0.9-1.3H26l0.5,0.8c0.2,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-0.5H27
   V67.3z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M27.9,68.2h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2H28c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8
   v0.8h-0.7V68.2z"></path>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="st1" d="M41.5,34.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.3h-0.9v-0.2H41.5z M40.4,35.5h0.3v0.9h-0.3V35.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M42,36.2c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3v-0.9H42v-0.2h0.5v1.1c0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.4h-0.2v-0.2H42z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M43.2,34.8v1.6h-0.3v-1.6H43.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M44.2,36.2h0.4v-0.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.4h-0.2l-0.3,1.4h-0.3l0.3-1.3h-0.3v-0.2h0.7c0.5,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8
   v0.8h-0.7V36.2z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M45.5,34.8v0.8h-0.3v-0.8H45.5z"></path>
  <path class="st1" d="M46.6,36.4v-1.3h-0.7v-0.2H47v0.2h-0.2v1.3H46.6z"></path>
 </g>
 
 
 
 
</g></svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dekel's, But in **Pure JS** :

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var areas = document.querySelectorAll('.svg_area');
var i = areas.length;
while(i--) {
  areas[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    svg.appendChild(e.target);
  });
}
```

**Demo :** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgeBeP

**Credit/Source :** https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YXoEQe